# show $I(a,1) + I(-a,1)\ge2$

Tags: calculus, integration

$I(a,b)$= $\int_1^e x^a\ln^bx \,dx, b > 0$

I need to show that $I(a,1) + I(-a,1)\ge2$

I took both integrals. For the first one I get:

$I(a,1)$= $\int_1^e x^a\ln x \,dx$ = $\frac1{(a+1)^2}$($ae^{a+1} + 1)$

The second one should be the same but $-a$ will take place for $a$.

Is there any elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $I(a,1)+I(-a,1)=\int_1^e (x^a+x^{-a})\ln x dx\ge \int_1^e 2\ln x dx=2$.

This is in fact the best possible since $I(0,1)+I(-0,1)=2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that $x^a+x^{-a}\geq 2$ over the interval you integrate over.